# Use embed variables in Expression Engine's channel tag?

Tags: expressionengine

I'm building a website that makes heavy use of image carousels. Each section has a different carousel with different slides.

Therefore, I've created an embed called `global_embeds/image_carousel.html` that contains the logic. It looks like this:

```
<div class="carousel">
{exp:channel:entries channel="homepage_carousel"}
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="{image}" alt="{title}" />
  </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</div>
```

As you can see, it's a simple HTML snippet that generates a `<div>` for each item. The problem, however, is that I want to use an embed parameter in the `exp:channel:entries` tag.

I tried calling the embed in my parent template like so:

```
{embed="global_embeds/image_carousel" carousel_channel="homepage_carousel"}
```

And changing my embed template to this:

```
...
{exp:channel:entries channel=embed:carousel_channel}
...
```

But it doesn't seem to be passing the variable value through as I'd like, instead just showing **all** entries in my carousel regardless of channel.

Am I going about this the right way? Or is there a better way to achieve what I'm after in Expression Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D'oh! Practically immediately after posting the question, I realised I can use the curly brace notation wrapped in quote marks:

```
...
{exp:channel:entries channel="{embed:carousel_channel}"}
...
```

Sorry to waste people's time.